# Can nftables perform postrouting matching on crgroupv2?

Tags: ubuntu, nat, nftables

I would like to change source address of every packet generated by a process in given cgroup (version 2). Is that even possible?

I have:

- `nftables 1.0.2`,
- `linux 5.15` (Ubuntu variant)
- `/system.slice/system-my-service.slice/my-service@1.service` cgroup

I have tried to:

- create a table `nft add table ip myservice`
- create a postrouting nat chain `nft add chain ip myservice postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100 \; }`
- try to create postrouting rule `nft add rule ip myservice postrouting socket cgroupv2 level 1 'system.slice' snat 10.0.0.1` (during experiments, I have used only `'system.slice'`, because nft has issues with `@` in the cgroup name, which would be level 2 issue :-).

I have found also `cgroup` matching which requires int32 argument, from which I guess it's cgroup version 1 (thus not applicable for me), because I have found no trace of hint for converting the path style cgroup to int.

I suspect the `socket` expression is not applicable to the postrouting nat chain, as the `nft` suggests in `Error: Could not process rule: Operation not supported`.

Do all the fails mean, that this is completely wrong approach?
Or have I just missed something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer to your two problems:

- syntax

  `cgroupv2` expects a path, which is a string. A string is always displayed with double-quotes, and requires double-quotes if it includes special characters. These double-quotes are for the `nft` command's consumption, not for the shell. With direct commands (ie: not in a file read using `nft -f`), these double-quotes themselves should be escaped or enclosed with single-quote, else the shell would consume them.

  In addition this path is documented as *relative* and doesn't need a leading `/` (anyway it's accepted and removed when displayed back), giving when directly from shell:

  ```
  socket cgroupv2 level 3 '"system.slice/system-my-service.slice/my-service@1.service"'
  ```

  Finally, `nft` doesn't care if it's given a single parameter with multiple tokens or multiple parameters one token at a time: the line is assembled and parsed the same. So whenever there's a special character for the shell (here `"`), just single-quote all the line rather than try to figure out where to escape characters (eg `\;` in base chains).
- work around the limitation

  You can mark the packet in output hook and check the mark in postrouting hook to do NAT.

  ```
  nft 'add chain ip myservice { type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept; }'
  nft 'add rule ip myservice output socket cgroupv2 level 3 "system.slice/system-my-service.slice/my-service@1.service" meta mark set 0xcafe'
  nft add rule ip myservice postrouting meta mark 0xcafe snat to 10.0.0.1
  ```

The final result can be put in its own file, with the two glue commands at start for [idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). Having its own file prevents any interaction with shell parsing, and gets atomic updates. It still requires `"..."` around the path parameter to not having *nftables* interpret the `@` character.

`myservice.nft`:

```
table ip myservice
delete table ip myservice

table ip myservice {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
        meta mark 0xcafe snat to 10.0.0.1
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        socket cgroupv2 level 3 "system.slice/system-my-service.slice/my-service@1.service" meta mark set 0xcafe
    }
}
```

which can then be loaded with `nft -f myservice.nft`, as long as the cgroup already exists (probably meaning, that at boot the service has to be started before *nftables* loads this rule).

In the end:

- every outgoing packet will traverse filter/output

  - if it's from a process in the adequate *cgroup* the packet will receive a mark 0xcafe
- every first packet of a new flow will traverse the nat/postrouting rule.

  - if it matches the mark 0xcafe (meaning it was in the adequate *cgroup*) this will trigger the SNAT rule for the flow (then the mark doesn't matter anymore)